# How to pass custom parameter in Suveyjs save results?

Tags: surveyjs

I want to pass custom parameter to surveyjs result data while saving. Currently 2 param available postId and SurveyResult, I want to pass the third one is it possible? How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Answered here - https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/issues/1925

Comment: Thank You so much.